# Ember-data - isDirty is true after commit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to save a form on submit but discard changes in any other case. The problem is that even after a commit the isDirty flag is true.

```
App.UserController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    enterEditing: function() {
    this.transaction = App.store.transaction();
    this.transaction.add(this.get('content'));
  },
  updateEditing: function() {
    console.log('update saved');
    this.transaction.commit();
    this.transaction = null;
  }
});
App.UserView = Ember.View.extend({ 
    templateName: 'edit-user',
    willDestroyElement: function() {
    console.log(this.getPath('controller.content.isDirty'));
    if (this.getPath('controller.content.isDirty')) {
      console.log('unsaved changes');
      this.getPath('controller.content.transaction').rollback();   
    }     
  }
});
```

And my router section:

```
showNew: Ember.Route.extend({
   route: '/user/new',
          cancelEditUser: Ember.Route.transitionTo('index'),
          connectOutlets: function(router) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('user');
            router.get('userController').enterEditing();
          }
        }),


  update: function(router, event) {
    router.get('userController').updateEditing();
    router.transitionTo('index');
  }
```

Comment: It should actually keep both `isDirty` and `isSaving` as true until your service returns a 200. After that, both flags should be automatically set to false. Check the `isSaving` flag, maybe your service hasn't finished saving it at the time you checked the `isDirty`

Comment: isSaving goes from false to true but isDirty stays true. I'm returning a 200 with a node.js/express backend - res.jsonp(200)

Comment: I'm also seeing this with FixtureAdapter on rc1